# Class File for SupportParentable in android.support.v4.app not found

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-actionbaractivity

So I just upgraded an ADT project to Android Studios, I've spent the day learning about Gradle and converting all the old imported libraries to compile lines, however I seem to be stuck on one final issue. The class:

public abstract class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity

Is resulting in 21 Errors. The first 4 are

Error:(14, 17) error: cannot access SupportParentable
class file for android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder$SupportParentable not found

Error:(31, 3) error: cannot find symbol variable super

Error:(42, 3) error: cannot find symbol variable super

Error:(47, 2) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

(Rest available if anyone thinks they're relevant)

I have support-v4 and appcompat-v7 compiled:

```
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1"
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1"
```

I've synced, cleaned and ran in all combinations. I'm not sure what step I'm missing here.

Yes I do know that ActionBarActivity has been depricated in place of AppCompatActivity, however switching to AppCompatActivity results in no noticeable changes. My focus right now is to get the project running as is and I'll look into modernizing after that.

Comment: anyone? I've posted to http://forum.xda-developers.com any other websites that might be valid?

Comment: Same problem here, any feedback?